# Buscar dato en lista desplegable desde un campo de texto

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, laravel

**¿Como podría lograr que desde un campo de texto pueda buscar un dato que se encuentra en una lista desplegable y que esta automáticamente busque el dato solicitado desde el campo de texto?**.

Encontré un ejemplo en **Javascript** muy interesante, pero al momento de llamar el campo de texto desde la función, me genera el famoso error: 
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

función javascript:

```js
function crit_busqueda() 
{
  var input=document.login.texto_busqueda.value.toLowerCase();
  //var output=document.getElementById('pro_id').options;
  var output=document.login.pro_id.options;
  for(var i=0;i<output.length;i++) 
  {
     if(output[i].value.indexOf(input)==0)
     {
         output[i].selected=true;
         console.log(output[i]);
     }                                      
     if(document.forms[0].texto_busqueda.value=='')
     {
         output[0].selected=true;
     }
   
  }
}
```

formulario en pestaña emergente:

```html
<form method="POST" id="login" name="login">
     <input type="text" name="texto_busqueda" id="texto_busqueda"class="form-control" onkeyup="crit_busqueda();"/>
     <select name="pro_id" class="selectpicker form-control" id="pro_id">
         @foreach($productos as $producto)
                 <option value="{{$producto->id}}">{{$producto->nombre_cargo}}</option>
         @endforeach
      </select>
</form>
```

segunda función que interactua con la lista desplegable:

```js
function agregarProducto() 
        {
            var sel = $('#pro_id').find(':selected').val(); //Capturo el Value del Producto
            var text = $('#pro_id').find(':selected').text(); //Capturo el Nombre del Producto- Texto dentro del Select

            @foreach($productos as $producto) 
                var id = <?php echo json_encode($producto->id); ?>;
                if (sel == id) 
                {
                    var sptext = text.split();
                    var newtr = '<tr class="item"  data-id="' + sel + '">';
                    newtr = newtr + '<td class="iProduct" >' + sel + '</td>';
                    newtr = newtr + '<td> <input  class="form-control" id="1" name="ListaPro" value="{{ $producto->nombre_cargo }}" /></td>';
                    newtr = newtr + '<td> <input  class="form-control" id="1" name="ListaPro" value="{{ $producto->descripcion_cargo }}" /></td>';
                    newtr = newtr + '<td> <input  class="form-control" id="2" name="ListaPro" value="0" required /></td>';
                }
            @endforeach


            $('#ProSelected').append(newtr); //Agrego el Producto al tbody de la Tabla con el id=ProSelected
            RefrescaProducto(); //Refresco Productos
            $('.remove-item').off().click(function(e) {
                $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove(); //En accion elimino el Producto de la Tabla
                if ($('#ProSelected tr.item').length == 0)
                    $('#ProSelected .no-item').slideDown(300);
                RefrescaProducto();
            });
            $('.iProduct').off().change(function(e) {
                RefrescaProducto();
            });
        }
```

**Estoy utilizando laravel como framework....**

Comment: No se mucho de JS pero... no tendría que ser `.val() == ''` en vez de `.value==''` ?

Comment: Es simple, forms[0] no es un elemento html, no existe, por lo cual no se le puede capturar su valor, debería ser output[0] en vez de form[0], pruebalo y me dices !

Comment: aparece lo siguiente: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Si no existe índice 0 por que lo usas en la parte de abajo ? output[0].selected=true;

Comment: se supone que el output[0].selected=true se ejecute cuando ninguno de los caracteres ingresados en el campo de texto corresponda a alguno de los elementos de la lista. Vuelve a llamar la posición 0 en la lista desplegable.

Comment: Quita ese document, deja solo if(output[0].texto_busqueda.value==''){.....

Comment: nuevamente:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined

Comment: Ah y quita el texto_busqueda se me olvidó ese jeje

Comment: jajajaj ahora: Uncaught TypeError: output[0].val is not a function. ¿no influye la propiedad:  onkeyup="crit_busqueda();" definida en el campo de texto?

Comment: Pero es value no val, no creo que influya el médoto

Comment: ahora no muestra error de sintaxis, pero me trae siempre el ultimo elemento de la lista

Answer (score -2):

Aqui funciona muy bien:

https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1111

Cambia document.forms[0] por document.login

y si quieres buscar por el nombre del producto cambia output[i].value por output[i].text

Comment: Hola Kuro, tu respuesta mas que respuesta parece un comentario y debería de ir en la sección de comentarios, pero no te preocupes, cuando tengas suficiente puntaje ganarás el privilegio de "comentar en todas partes", mientras tanto te invito a que te hagas el [tour] y sepas cual es el funcionamiento básico del sitio !

Comment: Exacto, cuando utilizo datos quemados en la etiqueta option del select funciona perfecto, pero cuando utilizo datos de la base de datos...ahi se genera el problema...vale aclarar que la lista desplegable interactua con dos funciones javascript mas. El campo de texto solo con la que genera el problema.

Comment: y el select descarga los datos una vez o cada cuanto realiza ese proceso?

Comment: descarga todos los datos de la base de datos de una sola vez

Comment: prueba a cambiar document.forms[0]. por document.login

Comment: aun me sigue trayendo el ultimo dato de la lista

Comment: es porque estas buscando por el campo value y este corresponde al id del producto, prueba a buscar un id de producto, si deseas buscar por texto debes cambiar output[i].value por output[i].text

Comment: disculpa la propiedad era .text para buscar por su texto en lugar de su valor

Comment: dice que el .toLowerCase(); no esta definido

Comment: lee los comentarios de arriba me había equivocado, no era esa parte la que debías cambiar, entonces edite el comentario

Comment: cambiar output[i].value por output[i].text

Comment: ya no saca error pero tampoco altera la lista de datos

Comment: https://codepen.io/jksa291193/pen/LOxMOv

Comment: @KevinSuaza, **debes [edit] tu respuesta** para que generes una respuesta de calidad así como lo es este sitio. Lee [¿cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) sección - Ofrece contexto para los enlaces.

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque solamente pusiste un link.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2883/).